# What is the correct way to run "const getStaticProps" with "useEffect"?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

`const getStaticProps` is for fetching API, I want to run this with:

```
useEffect(()=>{

    getStaticProps()
  })
```

but I get this error:

> ReferenceError: data is not defined

What is the correct way to run "const getStaticProps" with "useEffect"?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');
  const data = await res.json();
  var i = 0;
  return {
    props: { test: data.slice(0, (i += 10)) },
  };
};

function home({ test }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    getStaticProps();
  });

  return <h1>h1</h1>;
}
export default home;
```

Comment: you don't have to because getStaticProps should be automatically called.

Comment: `getStaticProps` is a special function in Next.js that allows the page to be statically generated, and fetch the data at build time. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props. You do not call it directly yourself, Next.js handles it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant nextjs `getStaticProps` method, there is no way to use both together. That method is to fetch data on server side. But `useEffect` will be fired after component rendering (client side).

Answer (score 0):

You can `await` for the promise to `settled` and take value

[`CODESANDBOX LINK`](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-nightingale-ielpre?file=/src/App.js)

```
import "./styles.css";

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos");
  const data = await res.json();
  var i = 0;
  return {
    props: { test: data.slice(0, (i += 10)) }
  };
};

function Home({ test }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fn() {
      const result = await getStaticProps();

      // Now you can use value result
      console.log(result);
    }

    fn();
  }, []);

  return <h1>h1</h1>;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Home />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: no need to write again the async function inside `useEffect` we can directly use `.then`

Comment: `useEffect(() => {
    getStaticProps().then((res) => setState(res));
  }, []);`   will work fine

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you probably want to use a variable to pass it to the view. If so, you need `useState` hook. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Here's could be a possible solution:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';  

function Home({ test }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const getStaticProps = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');
    const data = await res.json();
    setData(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getStaticProps();
  });

  return <h1>h1</h1>;
}
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

we can directly fetch the response using `.then` from promise in useffect

```
 useEffect(() => {
    getStaticProps().then((res) => {
      console.log(res.props.test);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

For getStaticProps no Need to call it. when you export function with name of 'getStaticProps' next automatically call it before component mount.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function Home({ test }) {

  console.log(test);

  return <h1>h1</h1>;
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');
  const data = await res.json();
  var i = 0;
  return {
    props: { test: data.slice(0, (i += 10)) },
  };
};

export default Home;
```